# Azure Service Bus - describe logic

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to have the following logic for Service Bus queue:

1. only one message in queue (storing datetime)
2. if we try to add new message never than added to queue - reject it

Is it possible?

Comment: Having a hard time to understand what you're after. First, queues are not designed to control how many messages they'll contain. They are designed to decouple between producers and consumers. Second, messages are not rejected by a queue (at least not with Service Bus). I can only think of message deduplication, but even then the sender will not know if the message was "rejected" or not. Could you clarify your question  a bit more?

Comment: @SeanFeldman I just need to get data from external resource by timer using Azure Function and pass date/time of last operation from previous call. So, I think to use Service Bus and pass last date/time as message with ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc in my timer interval

Comment: You can schedule messages, but you can't "reject". You can deduplicate based on a message id that could be a hash of the scheduled date/time.